# Bash, if statement issue

Tags: bash

I am new with bash and I try to use the `if` statement, so I tried this short piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["lol" = "lol"];
then
    echo "lol"
fi
```

And I get the following error:

> ./script.sh: line 2: [lol: command not found

I tried other combinations, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["lol" == "lol"];
then
    echo "lol"
fi
```

but I still get errors, so what would be the correct formulation ?

Thank you

Comment: You need a space after `[` and before `]` : `if [ "lol" = "lol" ];` Check your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the problem was solved in a comment above, let me give you a bit more information.

For Bash, `[` is a command, and there is nothing special about that command.  Bash parses the following arguments as data and operators.  Since these are normal arguments to a normal command, they need to be separated by spaces.

If you express a test as `["lol" = "lol"]`, Bash reads this as it would read any command, by performing word splitting and expansions.  This gets rid of quotes, and what is left after that is `[lol = lol]`.  Of course, `[lol` is not a valid command, so you get the error message you saw.

You can test this with another command.  For instance, type `l"s"` at the command line, and you will see Bash execute `ls`.

You would not write `ls/` (without the space), so for the same reason you cannot write `[a=b]` either.

Please note `]` simply is a closing argument that command `[` expects.  It has no purpose in itself, and requiring it is simply a design choice.  The `test` command actually is entirely equivalent to `[`, aside from not needing the closing bracket.

One last word...  `[` is a builtin in Bash (meaning a command that is part of Bash itself and executes without launching a separate process, not a separate program), but on many systems you will also find an executable named `[`.  Try `which [` at the command line on your system, it will probably be there.